# IPA notation for syllabic [n] after another [n]

Tags: ipa, german, phonetic-symbols

Written German has verbs like <*können*> ‘can’, but some (quick, lazy, …) speakers – myself included – pronounce this word form without any /e/ or schwa sound in the second nucleus. There are still two syllables, the usual IPA transcription [ˈkœnən] thus would be wrong (and so would be [ˈkœn̩ən] with U+0329 added to show the ambisyllabic status of the [n]). I’m not sure what would be the correct one: [ˈkœn̩], [ˈkœnn̩], [ˈkœn̩n̩], [ˈkœn̩ː]? It’s definitely not pronounced just [ˈkœn]! I even wondered whether it could better be described by a tonal marker, as in [ˈkœn↑].

Comment: [ˈkœnn̩]. IPA notation hardly depends on what precedes. And since the first syllable remains closed (doesn't it?), there must be a pure [n] there.

Comment: @YellowSky, make that an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Joe - OK, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be [ˈkœnn̩]. IPA notation hardly depends on what precedes. And since the first syllable remains closed (doesn't it?), there must be a pure [n] there. Besides, *könn-*, [kœn], is a distinct morpheme, there is no morpheme [kœ], so one still can break [ˈkœnn̩] into morphemes: [ˈkœn.n̩], which cannot be done with the other variants you suggested.

Comment: The first syllable remains closed indeed. You (and @Darkgamma) are probably right that [ˈkœnn̩] describes it best. I said “there are still two syllables” since [kœn]  is not it, but maybe it’s really just one syllable with a more complex coda or tone, e.g. [kœn↑] or [kœnː˥˩] (as suggested by Darkgamma).

Answer (score 1):

`[ˈkœnn̩]` is probably the one you're looking for. As far as I know, it's two separate sounds in German, so `[ˈkœn̩]` and `[ˈkœn↑]` are out of the question. `[ˈkœn̩ən]` is also out of the question because it would either be trisyllabic or have a non-syllabic schwa.

Comment: "it's two separate sounds in German"  - Is there any evidence for this (perhaps acoustic), other than the syllabic status of one but not the other?

Comment: That's the very evidence; one's syllabic and the other isn't. I mostly went of my native intuition and ears on this one, though. I've heard a small amount of people pronounce something resembling [kœn:˥˩] but it's usually [ˈkœnn̩] with two more-less separate [n]s.

Comment: You see [ˈkœn̩ən] or [ˈkœṇən] where people want to stress that – at least with “standard” pronunciation _Bühnenaussprache_ – the first [n] is both coda of the first and onset of the second syllable (hence hyphenation <_kön-nen_>). I’ve hardly seen [ˈkœn.nən] instead.

Comment: True but outside the scope of your question as you asked about the IPA representation of <können> with schwa dropping, which is [ˈkœnn̩]. [ˈkœṇən] otherwise doesn't exist (I am not aware of any uses of an underdot in the IPA) but [ˈkœn̩ən] is the more pedantic form, yes.

Comment: @Darkgamma As a rule, it's best not to postulate two phonemes where a single one can do the job. And here you just need a rule that if a syllable consists only of /n/ because of vowel elision, /n/ becomes syllabic. Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology#Consonants), which, like other analyses, does not posit two /n/ phonemes.

Comment: @robert I am not positing two phonemes, just a syllabic alternative. If we go by Wikipedia, there's also this: "If a sonorant follows in the syllable coda, the schwa often disappears so that the sonorant becomes syllabic, for instance Kissen [ˈkʰɪsn̩] ('pillow'), Esel [ˈʔeːzl̩] ('donkey')."